# vs2019 wxwidgets sample hello world -> "wxstrcoll not found"

Tags: wxwidgets

Seems like many people hit this and there seems to be no solution that I can find.

Follow exact instructions, downloaded precompiled libs, v 3.0.5 - latest stable build

```
set wxwin env var
make new 32bit empty project
copy the hello world app into new source file
set additional include
set preproc defintions -> UNICODE & _UNICODE on
set linker libs
```

build ->

```
1>------ Build started: Project: wxtest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>c:\work\wxwin\include\wx\wxcrt.h(487): error C3861: 'wxStrcoll': identifier not found
1>c:\work\wxwin\include\wx\wxcrt.h(487): message : 'wxStrcoll': function was not declared in the template definition context and can be found only via argument-dependent lookup in the instantiation context
1>c:\work\wxwin\include\wx\wxcrt.h(496): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'int wxStrcoll_String<const wchar_t*>(const wxString &,const T &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=const wchar_t *
1>        ]
1>Done building project "wxtest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you need to manually modify the header to fix the build with MSVS 2019 in 3.0.5 and remove `defined(__VISUALC__) ||` part of the check before `wxNEEDS_DECL_BEFORE_TEMPLATE` definition in `wx/wxcrt.h`.

FWIW this problem was fixed since a long time (~6 years) in wx 3.1 and you can compile 3.1.3 or the soon to be released 3.1.4 out of the box with MSVS 2019.

Comment: TY v  much. I also found that ‘conformance = no’ setting in Vic fixed it. But , so the ‘stable release’ version doesn’t compile the hello world sample. The web site says that 3.0.5 was released 3 months ago

Comment: Unfortunately what counts more is that 3.0 was released 6+ years ago, i.e. long before MSVS 2019, and so was never tested extensively with it and only minor fixes have been applied to it since then. If you're starting with wx development, please consider using 3.1 instead, it's much more appropriate in 2020.

Comment: P.S. I've applied [the fix](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/6354641c3bb798d9caf0a13c2fc5b3829c57bf3b) to 3.0 branch, so at least this will be fixed in 3.0.6 when it's released.

Comment: yup - changed to 3.1, fell into another hole. the prebuilt binaries instructions on the download page are from 2012, they do not work with 3.1 on vs2019, I found the web page update in a github checkin but the page is not the one shown on the download page.

Comment: I don't understand, the binaries from http://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/ definitely work with 2019... where did you find anything from 2012?

Comment: go here https://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/ click on the word 'here' under the big 'download windows binaries' blue button for vs2019. The page you get to has 2012 instructions that are incorrect. wxMSVC_VERSION_AUTO  should be something like wxMSVC_VERSION_ABI

Comment: ah, I see, it's the blog post which is out of date, not the binaries themselves, thanks; we'll fix this for 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I just add the definition wxNEEDS_DECL_BEFORE_TEMPLATE to the preprocessor definitions of the project to get rid of this problem.

Comment: This might only work on some platforms?  Also, it wouldn't fix other projects using wx on the same system.